# Get anchor tag to wrap at end of Paragraph?

Tags: html, css

I've got a paragraph with a link at the end of it like so:

```
<p>Some text, blah blah blah</p>
<a href="#">... read more</a>
```

This will end up rendering like this:

> Some text, blah blah blah
>
> ... read more

Except I want it to render like so:

> Some text, blah blah blah ... read more

Is there any way of doing this without placing the link inside the paragraph? I've wracked my brains for a few minutes and tried a few things but I'm getting nowhere.

Comment: can you use javascript/jquery? then the solution is http://jsbin.com/ikupav/1/edit

Comment: I think jQuery/JavaScript would be needless overkill for something like this, especially when you consider it wouldn't work for someone who doesn't have JavaScript enabled in their browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a bit of css to say:

```
p, a { display: inline; }
```

Comment: *duh* I feel stupid can't believe I hadn't tried that! Thank you :)

Comment: Happens to all of us from time to time :)

Answer (score 1):

create an overwrite for you paragraph element and change the standard style

```
p {diplay: block;}
```

to

```
p { display: inline-block; }
```

see link here: http://jsfiddle.net/SGAy3/​

Comment: That works, but only if the text is not multi-line, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8qJgw/

Comment: Removed the block: so just inline then. I work always with blocks, not used to adding content behind my <p>'s anyway. Thats why it's called a paragraph. Anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/8qJgw/3/

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
p {float: left;}
a {display: inline-block;}
```

The `display:inline-block` is to make sure the text link won't wrap

Answer (score 0):

stick a float:left to `a` tag and `p`tag..

So it may be like

```
p,a{float:left}
```